# Get 2 values from JSON array nodejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, parsing

I want to get two values from my JSON array. It looks like that:

http://pastebin.com/tm5StsZ3

I need to get a ID and key from these arrays.
Please help me, thanks.
I am using newest node js.

Comment: No, I just need it to call a function in library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through it like this:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
for(var myobject in jsonData){
     console.log("Id =" + myobject.id);
     console.log("key = " + myobject.key);
}
```

or like this:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
for(i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++){
     console.log("Id =" + jsonData[i].id);
     console.log("key = " + jsonData[i].key);
}
```

Comment: Id =undefined
key = undefined
Id =undefined
key = undefined
Id =undefined
key = undefined
Id =undefined
key = undefined
Id =undefined
key = undefined

Comment: Second one worked, had to remove one ( at start. Thanks @meda!

Comment: strange because it is supposed to be the same thing, anyway good luck

Answer (score 2):

ES6 syntax.

```
JSON.parse(data).map((item) => { item.id , item.key })
```

ES5

```
JSON.parse(data).map(function(item){ return {item.id , item.key }})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var val1 = arr[0].id;
var k1 = arr[0].key;
var val2 = arr[1].id;
var k2 = arr[1].key;
```

To get the array lenght use `arr.length`

Comment: How to check how many times i have to use arr[x].id? Amount changes.

Answer (score 0):

use map() function it will return te id and the key

```
var id = data.map(function(par){
    return  "id id :" +par.id+" key is: "+ par.key;
});
```

working see [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5df8d65w/)

Or you can is just a loop to access each key and id

```
for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
   console.log("Id is :" + data[i].id+"key is : " + data[i].key);
}
```